Primevue datatable conditional formatting of numerical data
I'm trying to format cells in a primevue datatable based on the value in the cell. I am basically following the docs example here, but it doesn't work. For my actual implementation I have dozens of columns and so need to dynamically loop through them. Here is a reproducible example.
<script setup lang="ts">
import DataTable from "primevue/datatable";
import Column from "primevue/column";

let data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({
  key1: Math.random(),
  key2: Math.random(),
  key3: Math.random(),
  key4: Math.random(),
}));

function formatterClass(data: {}) {
  return [
    "border-circle w-2rem h-2rem inline-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-sm",
    {
      "bg-red-100 text-red-900": data["key4" as keyof typeof data] < 0.3,
      "bg-orange-100 text-orange-900": data["key4" as keyof typeof data] >= 0.3 && data["key4" as keyof typeof data] < 0.6,
      "bg-teal-100 text-teal-900": data["key4" as keyof typeof data] >= 0.6
    }
  ];
};
</script>

<template>
  <DataTable :value="data">
    <div v-for="header in Object.keys(data[0])">
      <Column :key="header" :field="header">
        <template #header>
          {{ header }}
        </template>
        <template v-if="header === 'key4'" #body="slotProps">
          <div :class="formatterClass(slotProps.data)">
            {{ slotProps.data["key4"] }}
          </div>
        </template>
        <template v-else #body="{ data }">
          <div>
            {{ data[header] }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </Column>
    </div>
  </DataTable>
</template>


Primeview docs leave out a lot of details for the sake of brevity. I simply needed to import "primeflex/primeflex.css" to get this to work. Added this to my  style sheet: @import "primeflex/primeflex.css";
